# Getting multiple documents in firebase functions

Tags: c#, node.js, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to figure out how to loop through multiple documents, fetched in a firebase cloud function, in Unity, but not sure how?

Here is my cloud script:

```
exports.getUserData = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.HttpsError(
            'unauthenticated',
            'only autehnticated users can make requests!'
        );
    }

    const userData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get(data.userid);
    const myGroupMemberships = await admin.firestore().collection('groupMembers').where("playerId", "==", data.userid).get();

    var myGroups = [];

    myGroupMemberships.forEach(group => {
        const thisGroup = admin.firestore().collection('groups').get(group.groupId);
        myGroups.push(thisGroup);
    })

    return { "groups": myGroups };
});
```

As you can see, I first have to find the memberships for the user in "groupMembers", then loop through the records to get the group documents. I am not sure I am sending them correct, but thought that putting them in an array would be easies!?! Not sure thats the case.

In my Unity script I try to get them like this:

```
var func = FirebaseManager.instance.functions.GetHttpsCallable("getUserData");
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
data["userid"] = userId;

var task = func.CallAsync(data).ContinueWithOnMainThread((callTask) => {
    if (callTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // The function unexpectedly failed.
        GA.Log("FAILED!");
        GA.Log(string.Format("  Error: {0}", callTask.Exception));

        return;
    }

    var result = (IDictionary)callTask.Result.Data;

    // The function succeeded.
    GA.Log(string.Format("Whats in the groups: {0}", result["groups"]));

    List<Group> theGroups = result["groups"] as List<Group>;

    foreach (Group thisGroup in theGroups)
    {
        GA.Log("GroupName: " + thisGroup.groupName);
    }

});

yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted);
```

The log: Whats in the groups returns this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

I do not get any logs on the "Groupname" inside the foreach loop!

Where am going wrong and how should I accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)